# Apache Shiro credentials based security for Rest service

Tags: rest, jakarta-ee, shiro

I'm creating a App using Shiro as the security framework.
The app have two parts; Web and Rest.

The Web is using Shiro's default `FormAuthenticationFilter`. 
I'm happy with the session based approach.

The stand alone app which is using Rest, I want to limit from using the `FormAuthenticationFilter` and from creating a session, which I'm able to do via `shiro.ini` file

I need to implement credentials based security on the rest service.

Browsing on the web I saw some blogs suggesting that you create your own Realm and filter to handle this scenario. But no details on how to do this.

Is it possible to implement credentials based security on Apache Shiro? If so is there a blog or tutorial that shows you how to achieve this?

Regards

Comment: Can you please share a code repo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use basic auth for your webservice endpoints and form based authentication for the web.

Do web users also have access to your webservice?

EDIT:

Checkout this sample app. https://github.com/dominicfarr/skybird-shiro

It has three url paths configured in shiro.

web - uses form authentication.

api - uses basic authentication.

jersey - anonymous access.

Cutting to the shiro.ini config.

```
[main]
authc.loginUrl = /web/login.html

sessionManager = org.apache.shiro.web.session.mgt.DefaultWebSessionManager
sessionDAO = org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.eis.EnterpriseCacheSessionDAO

securityManager.sessionManager = $sessionManager
securityManager.sessionManager.sessionDAO = $sessionDAO


[users]
dom = password, user

[roles]
user = standard

[urls]
/web/login.html = authc
/web/** = authc
/api/** = authcBasic
/jersey/message = anon
```

Comment: Hi dom farr, do you mean `BasicHttpAuthenticationFilter` when taking about basic auth? Yes the web users can also use the Rest channel. Currently I'm looking at exactly that. I'm also using SSL so the connection is encrypted when using rest.

Comment: Thank you for the app. When calling the Rest services I want it to stay stateless (Good practice from what I'm reading), i.e not create a session for the user being logged in. I can use as you stated above `authcBasic`. My approach so far is on Rest to use `/resources/** = ssl[8443],noSessionCreation,authcBasic`. Which means Base64_encoded it with every request. Is there a way to override how `BasicHttpAuthenticationFilter` reads the header and decode it? want to encode/decode it with my own key.

Comment: I would add another question about override how BasicHttpAuthenticationFilter, so the answers aren't confused. But yes you can override most things in shiro.