# shiro token based security for exposing api

Tags: java, spring-mvc, shiro

I have implemented Shiro for log in in my webapp. But now i want to expose some of api for the outside usage. for this purpose each client will have a key or token which they will pass with each call.

I want  to understand how this mechanism should work and is this facility available with shiro because i am . not been able to find anything.

can somebody please help me to find some of the tutorials which i could go through.

My xml -

```
<listener>
<listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>classpath*:applicationContext/securityShiro.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<!-- The filter-name matches name of a 'shiroFilter' bean inside applicationContext.xml -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>shiroFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>targetFilterLifecycle</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<!-- Make sure any request you want accessible to Shiro is filtered. /* catches all -->
<!-- requests.  Usually this filter mapping is defined first (before all others) to -->
<!-- ensure that Shiro works in subsequent filters in the filter chain:             -->
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>shiroFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: I did it in a project before I used the cookie returned  in the authentication response. I've added it to the successive requests.

Comment: Check the answer of this question 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22528801/apache-shiro-token-based-security-for-rest-service